# When do I use mock.assert_has_calls in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, assertion

I struggling to understand what a use for `mock.assert_has_calls` could be.
The docs say

> assert the mock has been called with the specified calls.

Forgive me, but if mock something with a call, am I supposed to use this to make sure there's not an error in the source code of python, where my interpreter might decide say, "hummm, this function was mocked with the call Foo but I think I'm going to mock it out with the call Bar instead"?

Comment: It's is much more to ensure that all the mock calls, are done in desired order. Let's say you have 2 mocks that correspond to funcA and funcB respectively. The `assert_has_calls` will work as a ensurer that funcB was not called before funcA for any reason. If your workflow enable it happens, for any reason (perhaps a logic error) it will act. Example: the request could (or should) not happens before the db query (both behaviours mocked).

Answer (score 2):

You use [`Mock.assert_has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) to verify that your `Mock` has been called with specific sets of arguments.  "The specified calls" here refers to [`mock.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.call) objects, each of which represents a set of arguments for a specific function call.

Here is a simple example where we use `assert_has_calls` to verify that `foo` calls `bar(21, 21)` followed by `bar(40, 2)`:

```
from unittest import mock

def bar(a, b):
    return a + b

def foo():
    bar(21, 21)
    bar(40, 2)

@mock.patch(f"{__name__}.bar")
def test_foo(mock_bar):
    foo()
    mock_bar.assert_has_calls([
        mock.call(21, 21),
        mock.call(40, 2)
    ])
```

Comment: so I guess my question really is, how is this useful?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that.  The way your original question was phrased it didn't sound like you understood how you'd use this to test for bugs in *your* code rather than the Python interpreter (and I'd agree that it's not useful for you to be testing for bugs in Python itself).  Are you saying you're not sure why it's useful to test for bugs in your own code either?  Or you're not sure why it'd be useful for a test to verify that a particular function is called a particular way?

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out question. In the above answer, we call mock with a specific set of arguments. Then we test to see we called a mock with a specific set of arguments. That's like, "I'm going write my mom a mothers day card. But after that, I'm going to double check to test and make sure I wrote my mom a mother's day card!" How does that help? I just wrote it. How could I possibly NOT have written it, and why bother testing it?

Comment: What you're asking is basically "why do we have automated tests" which is a very big question but I'll give it a shot.  The answer is that code changes over time, and sometimes it's changed by lots of different people.  Suppose that you or somebody else accidentally changes `foo()` at some point so that it returns early, before it calls `bar` -- bam, `test_foo` fails!  As long as the person who changed `foo` is running the test before they commit the change (this is why CI systems exist), the test will tell them that they broke something important, before they actually break it.

Comment: The better version of your Mother's Day analogy would be if you called your mother to make sure she received the card, as a way of testing that the post office delivered it correctly.  That's much more how software development in the real world works (as opposed to small toy examples you work with as a student which tend to be very self contained) -- you're usually depending on a whole bunch of things to go right, some of which you don't have direct control or visibility of.

Comment: I mean, I get all that for sure, and I appreciate the effort you took to bring it up. But _in this specific example_ it just does 2 things:   mocks a call. Then checks that we mocked a call. This particular situation, not all automated testing, seems purposeless

Comment: No, the test *does not mock a call*.  It mocks the function `bar`.  `foo` (the code under test) is not mocked out at all.  The test verifies that `foo` calls `bar` by inspecting the calls to the mocked version of `bar` after `foo` has been executed.  You can verify the test by altering `foo` and seeing that the test fails; if the test were only testing the mock that it made itself, it would not be possible to make it fail by changing the code under test (which would indeed make the test pointless).